# How to not repeat `before_filter` code in each controller when it needs to apply to entire app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'd like to redirect all site traffic from all controllers to https while in production.  Probably using something like the following:

```
before_filter :redirect_to_https
```

With the following in the controller:

```
  def redirect_to_https
    redirect_to :protocol => "https://" unless (request.ssl? || local_request? || Rails.env.development? || Rails.env.staging? ) # probably don't need redundant development with `local_request` present
  end
```

What is the most effective way to apply this to all controllers vs having to repeat this in each controller?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `config.force_ssl = true` in your environments/production.rb config file.

If you want a before_filter to apply to all controllers, they all inherit from ApplicationController so put it in there.

Comment: Very good, thanks for that! As for the ApplicationController, I've seen some methods not seemingly inherited by other controllers so I am going to have to look into that further.

Comment: After attempting your suggestion, I'm getting the following: `Error 310 (net::ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS): There were too many redirects.`  Any ideas as to why this would occur?  Previously straight https worked fine.

Comment: This means there is an infinite loop somewhere. Did you add any before filters?

Comment: No additional before filters were added with your suggestion. Interestingly I do get the same error when I remove this line from production.rb and simply add a like before filter on one of the controllers.  It seems as though I'm darned if I do and darned if I don't.  Hmmm.  I'm not seeing anything that should evoke this loop.

Comment: It'll be because of your server configuration. Try searching for 'force_ssl <server> too_many_redirects'

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9267748/force-ssl-causes-never-ending-redirects
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7406749/multiple-redirects-in-rails-when-redirecting-to-https